# CDK codebuild project - put code in a subdirectory?

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-codebuild

I have the following `aws-codebuild` `Project` which gets some source from a Github repo, then does some build actions.

```
  const project = new Project(scope, "RaidoDbS3Import", {
    vpc: props.vpc,
    subnetSelection: { subnetType: SubnetType.PRIVATE_WITH_NAT },
    securityGroups: props.securityGroups,
    source: Source.gitHub({owner: "au-research", repo: "raido-v2"}),
...
```

I would like to change this to get the source code into a sub-directory, so that I can put some
data files in a sibling directory to the codebase.

I've looked around in the props for `Project` and `GitHubSourceProps`, but don't see anything that seems relevant.

My workaround will be to put the data files into an ignored subdirectory of the repository; but this questions is about "How can I clone the Github repository into a subdirectory of the codebuild current directory?"

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround can be using git submodules for your data and fetch it while cloning repo.

Comment: It'll be a cold day in heck before I choose to use Git as a staging tool for data files.

Comment: Still you can put files on any storage you want, prepare small bash script to get the data in place you want... and then module it with git ;)